# JSON from Java to JavaScript - Understanding which object it is

Tags: java, javascript, json, gson

I have a java servlet and a javascript app that communicate with json. I have one handler function in javascript that I use to handle the incoming data. My problem is that I'm sending different object classes to that one handler. For example, I might send a user object and an order object. What is the best way to understand which class it is in this javascript handler?

Should I really check if certain fields exist? Is that the best way?

If there i no elegant way, I guess using refactoring my app to use different handlers is the best way to go?

I'm using Gson, if it matters...

Answer (score 0):

You could always include an 'objectType' field in the returned json object which you can then use to determing it's type.

Refactoring does sound like a good idea here. It should really only be a matter of specifying the correct callback on the $.ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a KISS (Keep It Simple and Stupid) solution. Why don't you add a field indicating which is which like: ctype:'Java', ctype:'Js' or ctype:'MyJavaClass' ?